# how to determine underlying problems in a laptop with dying hard disk

Tags: laptop, hard-drive, livecd

I have a laptop with a dying hard disk. Linux said so when I booted using live cd of linux mint.
But how do I know if there's an underlying problem. 
For example, problems in the gpu. Which might make the graphics slow down.
Or any other problem. I've already wipe out my hard disk using dban and it took me almost 16 hours to do that on a 160Gb.
Is there any live cd that can be used to determine other problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a hard drive problem, then you have a hard drive problem.  If you are having a graphics problem, then you are having a graphics problem.  I'm not sure what you are getting at.

It is entirely possible to take your hard drive 16 hours to wipe with dban depending on the settings.

Answer (score 2):

[UBCD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) is the best tool I know of for general diagnostics. If you really want to go through the trouble, it is completely customizable, you can add any other diagnostic tools you want.